# Need help styling bootstrap container with jumbotron inside panel

Tags: angular, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

**I want to make the form inside the container fit inside the panel nicely**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="height: 657px; width: 600px; margin:auto;">

      <div class="panel-heading">A random header</div>

      <div class="panel-body">

          <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron" style="height: 615px; width: 600px;">


                <div class="form-group" >
                  <label attr.for="{{ 'instanceType'+ i}}">Instance Type<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                  <select  class="form-control" id="{{ 'instanceType'+ i}}" name="instanceType" formControlName="instanceType" required [(ngModel)]="presetInstanceType">
                    <option value={{presetInstanceType}} disabled selected>{{presetInstanceType}}</option>
                    <option>Service</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: I kept one dropdown box in the code for simplicity and readability purposes

Comment: You do realise there is no actualy form there right?

Comment: So why are you hardcoding the size of the jumbo?

Comment: @MikeOne by form I meant the drop down and other input boxes within the jumbrotron

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the issue. 
To fix the issue, remove the width and height that's set in your Div with class="jumbotron". And place the Div with class ="form-group", inside a container div.

Here is what your code should look like:

```
            <div class="jumbotron" >
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label attr.for="{{ 'instanceType'+ i}}">Instance Type<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="{{ 'instanceType'+ i}}" name="instanceType" formControlName="instanceType" required [(ngModel)]="presetInstanceType">
                            <option value={{presetInstanceType}} disabled selected>{{presetInstanceType}}</option>
                            <option>Service</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```